# MySQL database restore using PHP

Tags: php, import, mysql

I'm trying to restore MySQL dump created the following way:

```
$file = '/path/to/file.sql';
exec('mysqldump -u '.DB_USER.' -p'.DB_PASS.' '.DB_NAME.' > '.$file);
```

the above creates the dump as expected, then to restore I'm trying to use the following:

```
$file = '/path/to/file.sql';
exec('mysql -u '.DB_USER.' -p'.DB_PASS.' '.DB_NAME.' < '.$file);
```

but for some reason it doesn't do anything.

Please note that the constants contain the relevant database connection parameters.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try the full path of mysql, like `/usr/bin/mysql` or whatever and add some error checking on the `exec` call.  debug info?

Comment: Have you tested the string produced by PHP in a MySQL client connection to make sure it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `mysql -e 'source $file'` instead of redirection

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = realpath('file.sql');
exec('mysqldump -u ' . DB_USER . ' -p' . DB_PASS . ' ' . DB_NAME . ' > ' . $file);
```

Perhaps try this.