# MySql Source via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I call the equivalent line in PHP for this MySql line:

```
mysql> source [path-of-file].sql
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915460/mysql-database-restore-using-php) question seems fairly similar to yours...

Comment: This is non-trivial, because it involves parsing the queries with PHP. PHP is unable to execute more than one query at once. You *might* be able to `$queries = explode(';', file_get_contents('[path-of-file].sql')); foreach ($queries as $query) mysql_query($query);`, *but* if any of the queries contains a literal `;` or changes the delimiter at any point in the file, this will not work.

Comment: **Don't** pass the password on commandline, if you choose to go that road. Setup passwordless login instead, see [here](http://lmorgado.com/blog/2008/08/12/mysql-passwordless-login/) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOURCE is not a native mySQL command, but one specific to the command line client.

In PHP you could try something like:

```
<?php
shell( "mysql --user=$user --password=$password $database < $file" );
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, passing `$password` in a command is really what you should be doing ;)  Rather create a `~/.my.cnf` file including the password, and remove read-permissions for anyone but the user PHP is running as. That said; it's a viable (if not shaky) solution, so +1.

Comment: I am assuming its just a once off quick setup instead of a permanent solution :P

Comment: Although I understand this is probably a one-off solution, I'd still never recommend passing a password ;)

Comment: Thanks.
There are two of us developing and therefore we will be running the source command multiple times. 
Yes will add the password to the my.cnf file.